# Access violation exception while navigating to another page- windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am trying to navigate the user to the dashboard if he has already logged in to the app. When doing so I'm getting this exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in project.DLL

Here is my code..

```
private void dashboard() {
    try {
        Object signedinflag = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["userSignedIn"];
        if (signedinflag.ToString() == "True") {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/dashboard.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Console.Write(ex.InnerException);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead simply navigating using NavigationService change the RootFrame Navigation Of your Application On Application_Launching Event of App.Xaml.cs page.

**RootFrame** is the main container for all the pages so all the navigation will be handled through and it maintain your **Navigation Stack** also. So if you want to change the initial entry page of your application then you have to set the new page e.g Page1.xaml as the entry point in RootFrame content stack. You can also change the source of the rootframe or make it to navigate to new page like this

```
RootFrame.Source = (new Uri("/Page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

RootFrame.Navigate(new Uri("/dashboard.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

So your code will look like this.

```
 private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Object signedinflag = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["userSignedIn"];
            if (signedinflag.ToString() == "True")
            {
                RootFrame.Navigate(new Uri("/dashboard.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write(ex.InnerException);
        }

    }
```

Hope It Help you.